# postgres daily query analysis tool

Tags: optimization, postgresql, query-optimization, performance

does anyone know of a postgres view / function / tool that could report on the slowest and most often used slower queries? i think this would be so useful for all sysadmins. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL 8.4 comes with some addon modules that will help you with detailed analysis of this. They don't actually create reports, but they get you access to more data.

You can also look at pgfouine (http://pgfouine.projects.postgresql.org/). It generates nice-looking HTML reports.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote such a tool some time ago. You can get it [here](http://svn.depesz.com/svn/pgsql-tools/trunk) (file: `analyze.pgsql.logs.pl`)

There are (as of now) no real docs.

Comment: link is bad. answer is useless without it

Answer (score 1):

pgBadger is also good log analyzer tool that you can use.

Link: https://github.com/dalibo/pgbadger/downloads